# Por que a Comunidade♦ fechou essa pergunta?

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica, fechamento

Ontem eu marquei uma pergunta como possível duplicada, se tratavam de duas perguntas de um mesmo autor com a mesma dúvida.

[KSOAP ILLEGAL PROPERTY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57734/3117)

Hoje eu voltei na pergunta para ver se a comunidade (com "c" minúsculo) tinha concordado com  o meu voto e tinha escolhido pelo fechamento, eis que eu me deparei com a pergunta fechada pela [Comunidade♦](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidade) (com "c" maiúsculo e um ♦).

Por que a Comunidade♦ resolveu dar a opinião dela nesse caso e optar pelo fechamento?

Aqui está um exemplo em que a Comunidade♦ não atuou, sendo que também se tratava de uma duplicada de um mesmo autor: [Como colocar um break point em Web Service soap](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52956/3117)

Comment: Eu acho que essa `Comunidade♦` aparece quando há uma modificação no reabrir ou fechar, não tenho certeza, apesar de citarem como um "bot", percebi que as vezes quando cancelo uma situação, para lançar uma edição ou algo a mais sempre aparece `Comunidade♦`, não me lembro de um situação especifica, mas lembro que sempre aparecia isto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento deves estar a falar das edições para aprovação em que tu editas por cima certo?

Comment: Tipo isto? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27175

Comment: Isso mesmo @JorgeB. Acho que podem haver situações parecidas na reprovação, não tenho certeza.

Comment: Não tenho uma resposta, mas suspeito que algum usuário que não tenha privilégios de votar pra fechar tenha **sinalizado** a pergunta como duplicata, e o sistema tenha considerado que os votos mais as sinalizações eram "evidência" suficiente de que a pergunta poderia ser fechada como tal, e assim o fez (sem esperar os 5 votos normalmente necessários). Só um palpite...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Quase, veja minha resposta abaixo.

Comment: Já agora a pergunta tem uma resposta...

Comment: Muito bom chute @mgibsonbr, fazia muito sentido.

Comment: Pois é, a cirurgia foi um sucesso, só que o paciente morreu... :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eu também nunca tinha visto isso acontecer, e descobri que é um [recurso novo do sistema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) <sup>(@mgibsonbr, ó você lá!)</sup>. Quando a pergunta leva um voto de fechamento como duplicata, o seguinte aviso aparece para o autor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando o autor confirma que a solução do link resolveu o problema, o usuário Comunidade♦ vota para fechar, e o resultado é que ela é imediatamente fechada (Comunidade♦ é moderador), como aconteceu nesse caso que você mostrou. Se em vez de confirmar que resolveu a pessoa clicar no link de editar a pergunta, surgirá a seguinte orientação (que deve estar traduzida aqui):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bom recurso :).

Comment: Já agora falta traduzir o *title* ao passar com o rato em cima do Comunidade♦

Comment: Interessante,que bom que explicou. Agora só falta traduzirem os textos ;)

Comment: @Math Falta "o Gabe traduzirem", hahaha. Talvez ele já tenha feito isso até.